# getting an undefined variable error in firebug

Tags: javascript

Well, I am running the following function in my code and wondering why getting an error in Firebug which is as follows:

```
function TestSurvey(UniqueID, PhontTypes) {

            if(typeof(PhontTypes) != "undefined")
                PhontTypes = "4";

            if (PhontTypes.match("5")) 
            {
                window.location = some url location here...
            }
            else
            {           
                window.location = some url location here...                 
            }

    }
```

The error I am getting in firebug is as follows:

```
TypeError: PhontTypes is undefined

if (PhontTypes.match("5"))
```

Comment: Well, is `PhontTypes` undefined? Run a `console.log(PhontTypes)` right before your logic.

Comment: Perhaps try `== "undefined"` rather than `!= "undefined"`. As you have it, everything *but* `undefined` is replaced with `"4"`.

Comment: You mean I should change `if(typeof(PhontTypes) != "undefined")` to `if(typeof(PhontTypes) !== "undefined")` ?

Comment: @Jack The way your code currently works: in the event that `PhontTypes` is undefined, it stays undefined. In the event that it is defined, it is replaced by `"4"`. You want to reverse that behavior.

Comment: @Jack The problem is the "*not*" in `!=`. You want to check for equality rather than inequality. "*if PhontTypes **is** undefined, set it to `"4"` instead.*"

Comment: Man you only do thinks for defined variables so the existence of an undefined one is possible what's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `typeof` condition seems to be inverted. It's currently limiting `PhontTypes` to be only `undefined` or `"4"` -- nothing else.

To have it replace `undefined` with a "*default*" value of `"4"`, it should check for equality (`==` or `===`) instead:

```
// if currently `undefined`, set default
if(typeof PhontTypes == "undefined")
    PhontTypes = "4";
```

Or, since the next line expects [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to be available, you might replace all values that aren't `String`s:

```
if (typeof PhontTypes != "string")
    PhontTypes = "4";
```